# Gulp SVG Icons to output an HTML file for partial view

Tags: javascript, svg, gulp, pug, jade4j

So I am using GULP to build a SPA Styleguide for a large company. I have all of the SVG Icons being generated into a font in my gulp file. What I wanted to build was an HTML file I can use as a partial view (angular) so whenever someone tosses in a new SVG, it runs and generates a new HTML file every time, thus keeping the styleguide referencing this partial view up to date. I cannot get too complex because this will be handed off to a group of very Jr. developers. Here is what I have so far. When I run the gulp task, it is only building the first icon out of the 4 or 5 I have in there currently.

Gulp File (icon html file portion only):

```
gulp.task('fonts:build', function () {
    var re = new RegExp(/icon-(\w+)/);

    fs.readFile('www/Css/app.min.css', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        var icons = []
        if(err)
            return console.log(err);
        data.split('\r\n').forEach(function(icon) {
            var match = re.exec(icon);
            if(match)
                icons.push('icon-' + match[1])
        })
        // the gulp-jade plugin expects template local data to be an object
        // such as:
        // {locals: YOUR_DATA_OBJECT_TO_BIND}
        bind({locals: {icons: icons}})
    });

    // method that will bind data to your template
    var bind = function(data) {     
        gulp.src('Assets/Styles/Sass/CompanyNameFont/IconTemplate.jade')
            .pipe(jade(data))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('App/partials/icons/.'))
    }
});
```

Jade template for the output html file:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head
    body
        for ic in icons
            i(class=ic)
                |.
                = ic
```

Final HTML output from the Jade:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head></head><body><i class="icon-dependable">.icon-dependable</i></body></html>
```

As you can see I only have 1 icon listed but my min.css and my scss font files show 4 icons total.

Thanks for the help

Comment: what is `HTML Icon file` ? no such thing. change your title please to describe the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by just using gulp-iconfont-template.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-iconfont-template